# Get info from another layout to Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

**INTRODUCTION**

I'm practicing with canvas-graphics on android. For this I created an app where I can write a line with the finger, and erase it.

When I click the color palette, a dialog window appears with some colors. So I have 2 layouts:

1- The main layout

2- The palette layout

[image]

**QUESTION**

First I got the color palette in the main activity, and for each color button I have an onClick which calls to a method on main Activity.

The thing is that now I'm not able to do this onClick functionality. I think that it has something to do with that now I start this layout as a view instead as a layout, so the onClick functionality of each button doesn't work

This is palette.xml layout's button example:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
        android:background="#FF660000"
        android:onClick="paintClicked"
        android:tag="#FF660000" />
```

When I click on each button, it starts the paintClicked method an passes the color tag.

So, how do I have to initiate the palette layout when i click on the palette button, to be able to have the information passing from this layout to the main activity?

**UPDATE -- Current method to call palette.xml**

```
final Dialog paletteDialog = new Dialog(this);
paletteDialog.setTitle("Colores:");
paletteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.palette);

LinearLayout paletteLayout = (LinearLayout) paletteDialog.findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
bnColor = (ImageButton) paletteLayout.getChildAt(0);
bnColor.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed));

paletteDialog.show();
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: paintClicked [class android.view.View]
```

This is the paintClicked method reference:

```
public void paintClicked(View view){
```

Comment: Try to set the onClick from code

Comment: @simoneL I can set the onClick with code for the main Activity's layout' items, but how I do this to handle a second layout's items like palette layout?

Comment: The Dialog object has a findViewById method that helps to retrieve an inner view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at `DialogFragment` (if you aren't using it already). You can create a simple callback interface so that when a color is clicked, it calls back to the enclosing `Activity` with this information. Make the enclosing `Activity` implement the interface (enforced by the `onAttach` lifecycle method below) and have the dialog fragment call it when a color is picked.

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Define a callback interface
    public interface OnColorSelectedListener {
        public void onColorSelected(int color);
    }

    private OnColorSelectedListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        if (!(activity instanceof OnColorSelectedListener)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement OnColorSelectedListener!");
        }
        listener = (OnColorSelectedListener) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        listener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.palette, container, false);

        // call view.findViewById(...) for all your color buttons and
        // set the OnClickListener
        view.findViewById(...).setOnClickListener(this);
        ...

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Colores:");
        builder.setView(view);
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /* 
         * Determine the color from the view that was clicked. You can use a
         * switch statement on v.getId() if they all have IDs, but there are
         * other possibilities as well.
         */
        int color = ...;
        listener.onColorSelected(color);
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I start then the dialogFragment in my main Activity when I click on the palette button? Could you provide an example?

Comment: You use FragmentManager and/or a FragmentTransaction. The documentation on DialogFragment explains how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

android:onClick only works if the Context which expanded the view contains the function ("paintClicked" here).
So if you didn't expand this layout with your main Activity it could the reason it doesn't work.

It might be better for you to set Ids to the ImageButtons and use some findViewById(R.id.btnX).setOnClickListener(myListener); after displaying the buttons.

Comment: I updated the post with the method. When I start the dialog, I pass `this` context, so this wouldn't be enought?